# Permalinks not working for wordpress MU, images not showing up - .htaccess Problem

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I moved 3 different wordpress installations to one single Wordpress MU.
Every thing except Permalinks are not working and images are not loading on the webpages.

Image URL style
**http://subdomain.domain.com/files/2009/05/image.gif** I get 404.
but if change i change it to **wp-content/blogs.dir/4/files/2009/05/image.gif** It works perfectly fine.

I tried almost everything with .htaccess file.

My mod_rewrite is active.
I am setting up this on an EC2 Instance.
Pls help.

Comment: Posting your .htaccess file would be helpful.  It seems that's where the real issue may be.

Answer (score 0):

Are you are using suPHP as your PHP handler? If so and you have all of your files set to executable, then this could trigger your problem.

Under suPHP you must have strict and secure file permissions (644 for files, 755 for directories) or else your site will not function as you intend it to. Using suPHP also runs php as the domain's user rather than nobody, which is another security gain.